# Echoing in blade.php vs in php file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

When I write the following code in a blade.php

```
<php echo $posts; ?>
```

It works fine, but when I write

```
{{$posts;}}
```

It gives me an error saying:

> syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'

If `<?php echo ?>` is same as `{{ }}` why is writing ";" a problem in blade syntax?

Comment: Blade has its own syntax, which translates to PHP. The curly quotes translate to echo, and putting a semi-colon in there will throw off the syntax when it gets parsed.

Comment: That said, I can't duplicate it. When I do `{{ json_encode($items); }}` in my own blade file, it converts it to `<?php echo json_encode($items);; ?>`, as shown in my `storage/views/` files.

Comment: I would think the reason is blade's engine at its base level does a simple search and replace of variables within the tags.

Comment: @aynber helped me a lot!

Comment: Was curious, so did some digging. trait CompilesEchos got this piece of code: `"<?php echo {$wrapped}; ?>{$whitespace}"`. Also, for some quick exploration, this is quite nice: `dd(Blade::compileString('{{ $test }}'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the compiled view.
You'll see something like this:

```
<?php echo e($posts;); ?>
```

Now can you see the syntax problem?

What the curly braces do in the Blade is simply supply it to the [`e` helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-e) and then echo the result. Having a semicolon in a function is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 3):

> why is writing ";" a problem in blade syntax?

The answer is that the templating engines "Blade" has this rule in the core, so when you use `{{ }}` you shouldn't pass semicolon `;` at the end.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove semicolon after **$posts**

```
 {{ $posts }}
```

Comment: The question is *why is writing ";" a problem in blade syntax?*. This doesn't answer that, or even tell the OP anything they haven't already stated in the question.